# Saving Multiple Options in Single Field

Tags: sql-server

I need to save multiple options into a single field so that I didn’t have to create a column for each option. The options that can be selected will increase over time so using columns will probably not be the best way to go with this... One too many options can be selected at a time and save to the database.

So I have come up with the following solution and was wondering if there was a better way to do this and also if anyone can see any issues with it. I have done testing and it seems to work fine for the variations I selected.

Method:
Assign all the options a unique prime number, let the user select the options he wants, multiply the selected option’s corresponding prime number and save the resultant value in the field. 
When checking if the option was selected: 
 If the number saved is divisible by the prime number without a remained, that prime number’s corresponding option was selected by the user. 
Eg:

- Monday 2,  Tuesday 3,  Wednesday 5,  Thursday 7,  Friday 11, 
  Saturday 13,  Sunday 17

Selection: 
Monday, Friday, Sunday 
2 * 11 * 17 = 374

```
**Monday** = 374/2=187,  (Or 374 % 2 = 0)
Tuesday = 374/3=124.6666666666667, 
Wednesday = 374/5=74.8,  
Thursday = 374/7=53.42857142857143, 
**Friday** = 374/11=34,  
Saturday = 374/13=28.76923076923077, 
**Sunday** = 374/17=22
```

Comment: How many options (as written in the title) you currently have & anticipate in future?

Comment: At the moment we have seven options. I am using this for our database maintenance routines so it is difficult to tell now how many it will go up to, we add additional things as issues arise… To that end, I have found a problem with this approach in that multiplying the numbers together lands up being quite large. Just checked and this overflows on 29. So this would only work with a small number of options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use de bitwise permissions pattern. Basically you store each option as a power of 2. In this way you can have all the posible combinations in a single integer field. Just google Bitwise persmission to implement the solution

Answer (score 3):

Use rows. This seems to be a standard many-to-many relationship.

Create a table to hold the options, then another table to relate options to whatever the original table was.

Further reading: http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php

Comment: This is the best way to go if it satisfies your requirements.  My XML answer works but proper relational design is definitely superior.

Comment: I do agree. We have  been using joining tables for this kind of thing all over our server. The problem is now our databases are riddled with joining tables, procedures, functions and even table columns that we aren’t even sure we use anymore. I now try keep things to a minimum when developing and felt this reduced some of the objects that would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems particularly cryptic.  If you *must* store multiple pieces of data in a single column, consider using XML.  With an XML-typed field, you can store structured data in a relatively clean form, and use XQuery to at least have a chance to query and use it in a way that's compatible with other SQL queries.